# Windows 10 Privacy settings locked, breaking microphone and Camera

Tags: windows-10, webcam, microphone

Since I update my computer yesterday, none of my apps have access to my camera or my microphone and my settings app says *settings are hidden or controlled by your organization.
[Mic settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxHI1.png)

[Cam settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9uuZ.png)

[Mic settings 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HC31S.png)

[Winver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lo8W9.png)

[sysinfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHLAs.png)

[Diag & Feedback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXFKQ.png)

I have tried many different solutions and none have helped or fixed the issue.

I reinstalled my drivers but now even more things are broken.

I would just revert to a restore point but every time I try it fails.

Comment: “some settings...” appear for two reasons.  The first you have a related seting that needs to be enabled disabled.  The other is your joined to a domain.

Comment: Can you tell me this related setting? Also I have not joined a domain. The sysinfo screenshot clearly shows my domain as "workgroup" meaning a local domain.

Comment: I don’t know which settings you have disabled, so I can’t tell you, which setting to enable.  If you just installed 1803, you were presented an opportunity to enable and disable certain privacy settings, start with those settings you disabled.

Comment: Make sure you have not disabled telemetry

Comment: I tried it with telemetry enabled and set to high and low settings. Nothing yet has fixed it.